# Is there any good Cognitive Architecture to model intelligent tutoring system?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling, artificial-intelligence

Being a bugging AI and CogSci researcher, I have so far found J.Andersons Act-R based ITS (Intelligent tutoring system) model, it seems very laborious.

Is there any good current day Cognitive Architecture to design an intelligent system such as interactive tutoring systems which can be used to assist students in solving exercises and in improving problem solving skills?

Comment: Can you explain why ACT-R does not fit your requirements, or what your requirements are?

Comment: ACT-R does facilitates requirement of an interactive cognitive tutor,but i want to try to implement it in other architectures like SOAR which seems very promising too, but i am not sure of it, so seeking for a guidance :)